# How can i select the namespace definition tag with an xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

I have the below example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<my:root xmlns:my="http://www.example.com/mynamespace">
<my:child name="Sid">
<my:grandchild name="Sue">
<my:greatgrandchild name="Fred" />
</my:grandchild>
</my:child>
</my:root>
```

and i need to select the attribute xmlns:my using an xpath but it is not working.
Can someone please advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With XPath 1.0 (and possibly some vendors that still support it in later versions), you can use the `namespace::` axis:

```
/*/namespace::my
```

or

```
/*/namespace::*[name()='my']
```

With XPath 2.0 and greater, you can use the [`fn:namespace-uri-for-prefix()`](http://w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-namespace-uri-for-prefix) and [`fn:in-scope-prefixes()`](http://w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-in-scope-prefixes) functions:

```
fn:namespace-uri-for-prefix("my", /*)
```

Comment: Note also, this reports all namespaces that are in-scope for a particular element, including those declared on ancestor elements: it's not confined to namespaces actually declared on the element in question. And in the XPath data model, namespaces are not modelled as attributes; they're a different kind of node.